# Do Blizzards from multiple Wizards stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

The description of [Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/blizzard) states "Multiple casts in the same area do not stack."

What if there are two Wizards in my party? Will each of their Blizzards deal damage, or only one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brant and I have just tested this, and it appears that Blizzard does stack between different Wizards, much like any other DoT or effect stacks per player.

This means you'll never be penalized for having the same class as a party member, which is always a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK if they are casted at the same time they do not deal double damage, need to cast them one after the other

Answer (score 0):

Even if more than one Wizard casts Blizzard in an area, there are still "multiple" casts in the same area, therefore the damage does NOT stack.

Comment: This has been proved false with testing. Only blizzards cast by the same wizard do not stack with each other.