# Does Blizzard from multiple Wizards stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can multiple Wizards cast Blizzard at the same time?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68156/can-multiple-wizards-cast-blizzard-at-the-same-time)

The tooltip on Blizzard clearly states:

> Multiple casts in the same area do not stack

which is actually a bit ambiguous. If you have multiple wizards casting blizzard on the same spot, do those blizzards at least stack?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When two different Wizards can use Blizzard at the same time, both will deal damage.

When the tooltip says "Multiple casts in the same area do not stack", it is referring to multiple casts *from the same character*.